# How to create productFlavors from a json configuration file in build.gradle?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

In an android project, I need to build dozens of flavors, each is for a different school, the only differences between each flavor are the app name/application id.

The file build.gradle in under source control, so I want to make a ever-changing configuration file in json format, so to add/remove a flavor, there's no need to alter "build.gradle", the configuration file likes:

```
[
    {"name": "school1"},
    {"name": "school2"}     
]
```

my question is how to read this configuration and create the productFlavors dynamically?

Comment: This question is interessant, but I can't figure out why you need to do so instead of using static flavors?

Comment: Gradle is a Groovy DSL. You can use Groovy to parse the JSON, then iterate over your array of data and call the appropriate Gradle methods to define the flavors.

Comment: @MarcEstrada these schools are added/removed dynamically in a website (this website is developed by us too) and I want to automate the whole build process without human interference,  surely I could modify build.gradle directly, but 1. build.gralde is under source control,  if both machine and programmer could change it, it may be very difficult to maintain and the whole process sucks: suppose if I want to add a dependency in build.gradle, but firstly, I must check if the productFlavors is modified in product environment. 2. it is much easier to parse/modify a json file than build.gradle

Comment: Great, this idea is really interesting!

Comment: @MarcEstrada check my answer please

Answer (score 3):

After learning some groovy and gradle (since I really feel very confused about gradle in the beginning), here's the short answer:

change from this

```
{
    flavorDimensions 'school'   
    productFlavors {
        fooFlavor {
           dimension 'school'
           // more configurations
        } 
        barFlavor {
           dimension 'school'
           // more configurations
        }
    }
}
```

to:

```
{
    flavorDimensions 'school'   
    productFlavors {

        create('fooFlavor') {
           dimension 'school'
        } 
        create('barFlavor') {
           dimension 'school'
        }
    }
}
```

full answer: 
    import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;

```
productFlavors {
    def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
    def orgs = slurper.parseText(new File('../orgs.json').text)
    for (org in orgs) {
        create(org.domain) {
            dimension 'org'
            applicationIdSuffix ".${org.domain}"
            resValue 'string', 'app_name', "${org.name} School"
            // add a meta-data in your AndroidManifest.xml like
            <meta-data android:name="SERVER_PREFIX" android:value="${SERVER_PRERIX}" />
            manifestPlaceholders.SERVER_PREFIX = "http://${org.domain}.xxxx.com"
        }
    }
}
```

The following is the explanations:

BACKGROUND KNOWLEDGE

build.gradle is a dsl written in groovy, and `productFlavors` is a closure (but only in groovy, not the same as what closure means in javascript etc. you could just consider it a to be a function ROUGHLY), the following is an example of groovy's closure:

```
def closure = { a -> "hello, $a" }
// or, just using it (stands for the argument whatever it is)
// def closure = { "hello, $it" }
assert closure('world') == 'hello, world'
```

and closure has an important builtin property `delegate`, which means you could delegate to some other things to execute, the following is an example:

```
def cl = { greet() } // you may wonder where's greet

class Greeter {
    public greet() { println 'hello' }
}  
// delegate to a greeter
cl.rehyderate(new Greeter(), this, this)
cl() // 'hello'
```

groovy could remove the parens in method-calling (you may see it in coffeescript). here is an example:

```
def f(a, b, c) {
    a + b + c // omit return just like coffeescript
}

assert f(1, 2, 3) == 6
assert f(1) 2 3 == 6
```

so the previous code is the same as:

```
 {
    flavorDimensions('school')   
    productFlavors({
        create('fooFlavor', {
           dimension('school') // this is not a configuration, but just a plain method call
        })
        create('barFlavor', {
           dimension('school')
        })
    })
}
```

here productFlavors accepts a closure as argument, and it [delegate](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.BaseExtension.html#com.android.build.gradle.BaseExtension:productFlavors(org.gradle.api.Action)) [NamedDomainObjectContainer](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/NamedDomainObjectContainer.html%20NamedDomainObjectContainer) to execute this closure, and NamedDomainObjectContainer has a method `create` to create a flavor

Comment: Nice investigation!! Congrats